# how to retrieve data from phpmyadmin table with angularjs $http?

Tags: php, angularjs

i can send data to the table, but i can't retrieve  data. this is
 the code that i tried. i want to show details of the table in a html page.
i can't understand why this code isn't working. can anyone help?

php code:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hamatkin');
    if(!$con){
        die("couldnt connect".mysqli_error);
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
    $result = $con->query($query);
    $r = array();
    if( $result->num_rows>0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $r[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $res = json_encode($r);
    echo $res;
?>
```

Controller:

```
"use strict";
var app = angular.module('dataSystem',[]);
app.controller('customerListCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $http({method:'GET', url:'get-allCustomers.php'}).success(function(response){
        $scope.customers = response;});
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <table ng-controller="customerListCtrl" >
        <tr ng-repeat="x in customers">
            <td> {{ x.customer_id}} </td>
            <td> {{ x.first_name }} </td>
            <td> {{ x.last_name }} </td>
            <td> {{ x.id}} </td>
            <td> {{ x.city}} </td>
            <td> {{ x.adress}} </td>
            <td> {{ x.phone}} </td>
            <td> {{ x.email}} </td>
            <td> {{ x.fax}} </td>
            <td> {{ x.referrer}} </td>
            <td> {{ x.comments}} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: php code is the code for =>  get-allCustomers.php

Comment: use the Net tab in firebug/developers tools to understand if ajax call is done and see if there is an error in it

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `response.data` instead of `response` only

IMPORTANT:

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

```
"use strict";
var app = angular.module('dataSystem',[]);
app.controller('customerListCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $http({method:'GET', url:'get-allCustomers.php'}).then(function(response){
        $scope.customers = response.data;
    }, function(response){
       //Your errorhandler
    });
});
```

To improve readability you could also use the a shorter version for your get request:

```
$http.get('get-allCustomers.php').then(function(response){
    $scope.customers = response.data;
}, function(response){
   //Your errorhandler
});
```

Answer (score -1):

please try

```
 <?php
      $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hamatkin');
      if(!$con){
      die("couldnt connect".mysqli_error);
      }
      $query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
      $result = $con->query($query);
      $r = array();
      if( $result->num_rows>0){
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      $r[] = $row;
      }
      }
      $res = json_encode($r);
      echo $res;
die();
      ?>
```

add die(); function

Comment: i added but still tthe same